# Removing the last element of a list

Tags: list, deletion

Is there a simpler way to remove the last element of a list than this?

```
(setq list (reverse (cdr (reverse list))))
```

Comment: If doing that, you would likely want to be using `nreverse` (destructive) rather than `reverse` (copying), for the sake of efficiency.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes there is:

`(setq list (butlast list))`

That is a function from `subr.el`. (Loaded by default. No need to load anything.)

You can also cut a tail with `N` elements by

`(setq list (butlast list N))`

---

A word about phils' comment:

> If it's safe to modify the original list structure, then `nbutlast` will be slightly more efficient (n.b. you still need to assign the result back to the variable).

The comment is right and useful but it has to be considered very cautious.

For an exmple the application of `nbutlast` is safe if the following three conditions are fulfilled:

- if you are in a pure function (you have **local** non-leaking **bindings**)
- you generate the list **from its elements** within the function
- you want to split off the last element **at the end** of the function (i.e. in the last evaluated form before exiting the function)

Be aware that `nbutlast` modifies the argument `list` in the calls of the following functions!

```el
(defun queue (el list)
 "Prepend el and remove last element."
 (nbutlast (cons el list)))

(defun foo (head list)
 "Prepend head and remove last element."
 (nbutlast (append head list)))

(setq list (list 2 3 4))

(queue 1 list)

list ;; -> (2 3)

(foo '(1) list)

list ;; -> (2)
```

Comment: If it's safe to modify the original list structure, then `nbutlast` will be slightly more efficient (n.b. you still need to assign the result back to the variable).

Comment: Note that behind the scenes, these functions are using `setcdr` to modify the `nthcdr` where N is based on the `length` of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use `dash.el`'s slicing:

`(setq list (-slice 0 -1 list))`

I don't know if this is too much 'soy' for those hardcore lispers, but `-slice` really takes the hassle out of lists for me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The sequences library bundled with Emacs makes this easily generalized.  Here I demonstrate a possible implementation in an IELM buffer.

```
ELISP> (defun seq-butlast-elt (seq)
         "Return a copy of SEQ without its final element."
         (seq-take seq (1- (seq-length seq))))
seq-butlast-elt
ELISP> (seq-butlast-elt '(1 2 3))
(1 2)

ELISP> (seq-butlast-elt '(1))
nil
ELISP> (seq-butlast-elt '())
nil
ELISP> (seq-butlast-elt ["oak" "cherry" "apple"])
["oak" "cherry"]

ELISP> (seq-butlast-elt ["apple"])
[]

ELISP> (seq-butlast-elt [])
[]

ELISP> (seq-butlast-elt "dogs")
"dog"
ELISP> (seq-butlast-elt "d")
""
ELISP> (seq-butlast-elt "")
""
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html

This might not be the fastest possible implementation.